# How to rename a field in a Django form?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a custom Django widget that renders some HTML that I cannot control, and by default the widget's HTML will has a fixed name attribute using a `-`, say `name="field-name"`. My problem is that Django expects the name attribute in the HTML to be exactly the same as the variable name of the field in python. But of course in python I cannot name a variable using `-`.

Is there any way to tell Django to decouple the variable name of the form field from the name in the HTML? In other words, when the user already introduced the data in the field and sends the POST request, can I tell Django that the field `field_1` should be reading the value `field-name` from the requests.POST dictionary?

Comment: You can always `self.fields['field-name'] = TheField()`, can't you?

Comment: This is how django takes the value. You either need to overwrite the `BoundField` or the widget. https://github.com/django/django/blob/3f9d85d95cab228fd881ea952c707022e9e3bdf3/django/forms/boundfield.py#L138

Comment: Thanks, this took me to realize that I can access the complete POST querydict in `value_from_datadict` and grab the value of `field-name` from there.